# ASP Core 2.2 Localization of Identity InputModel from Login

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-localization

In my ASP Core 2.2 application I use Localization to make my application multi-language. Everything is working fine for the Controllers, Views and Models.
I make use of the scaffolded Login page. There the View is also translated as expected.
But I can't seem to get the Model (InputModel) translated. I probably have my resource location incorrect, but I can't figure out what is wrong.

So the question: How can I translate the ErrorMassgaes from the InputModel in the Login.cshtml.cs in the Areas Identity.

[This is my folder structure for the Identity and Resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnv9U.png)

Comment: Hi @SHunter, From the screenshot, it seems that you are setting the localization error message for the Login model and LoginViewModel, without setting for the InputModel.  And, have you ever used the DataAnnotations to add the error message in the InputModel?  Please check it and try to add DataAnnotations in the InputModel, Or you could create a new View Model with all required properties and add DataAnnotations, then add resource file for the new ViewModel. Reference: [DataAnnotations localization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ZhiLv, I use DataAnnotations in the rest of my application without problems. I tried to also set the messages for the InputModel (with LoginModel.en.resx), but without effect. Any ideas how I can solve this? Greetings, Sander